# Unity Android Drag Aim Release

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I need help with (what I believe to be simple but I don't know) something (for android): I have a 2D ball, that is on a simple square table (you see it from above so I don't need gravity), I want to drag from that ball and release and upon release the ball goes in that direction or in opposite direction if you drag "behind" the ball. Just put your finger on the ball then drag and release. I searched for 2 days on forums and youtube and everywhere but I couldn't find what I need. I found something but it's really outdated and does not help me. Thank you for your help! And I am sorry for taking your time if there is already something answered that I didn't find!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you have a Rigidbody2D and collider attached to your ball and will launch the ball in the opposite direction that you drag.

```
Rigidbody2D rbody;
Vector2 startpos;
Vector2 endpos;
float power = 5f; // power of shot

void Start()
{
    rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        endpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        LaunchBall();
    }
}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    startpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}

void LaunchBall()
{
    Vector2 direction = (startpos - endpos).normalized; // swap subtraction to switch direction of launch
    rbody.AddForce(direction * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome man! I've spent my last 2 days searching for this! is there a way you can teach me how to create that arrow that shows the direction?

Comment: thats a bit complicated to answer in a comment! i'd suggest starting by instantiating a sprite of an arrow that rotates with the direction vector as you drag. to update the rotation continuously, you'll need to modify the above code a bit to continuously get the mouseposition while you aim.